# Jaspersoft Ireport doesn't support UTF-8 queries (Hebrew language)

Tags: utf-8, jasper-reports, ireport

in Ireport 4.8.0 
i need to write query with a "where" phrase that include a "UTF-8" word, like this:

SELECT
     accounts.`name` AS accounts_name,
     accounts.`billing_address_city` AS accounts_billing_address_city
FROM
     `accounts` accounts
WHERE
     accounts.`name` = "מיינפורם"

when i write it in Ireport, it doesn't find anything because it doesn't recognize the UTF-8 word in the where clause:

[image]

when the same exact query does work in the MySQL database:

[image]

So the problem is in the Ireport that deosn't recognize the UTF-8 word, 
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by defining a new database connection and this time with the following parameters:

jdbc:postgresql://IPAddress/DatabaseName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

From this point on, the report query started to return results.

Comment: Of course. If you don't specify, your connection will use some default (probably JVM default, sniffed from the underlying OS). You probably got ISO-8859-1 or Windows-1250 or something which just isn't going to work. When you specify UTF-8, it works.